# To remove non- pair entries in a dataframe?

Tags: r, sorting, linguistics, phonetics

A column 'Consonant' in my dataframe 'df' has two levels with numbers, 250 for 'Geminate and 214 for 'Singleton'. Because Geminates are more in number, how can I remove the extra entries for Geminates, so to equate with the 'Singleton'? The output should be so that only those entries for 'Geminate' should remain that have their counterpart in 'Singleton'. The first two characters in Column 'Filename' denotes the Speaker, followed by the token word tested.

My dataframe has 13 columns and 464 rows, thus, posting a picture (knowing it is not encouraged). Thanks in advance for your help. Regards.

[A snippet of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JMYW.png)

EDIT: The output from dput()are in the link provided (since I could not paste it here, exceeding character limit).
[dput() output](https://opacity.io/share#handle=b589d3b06db9da020a1a61f53b1d6c1fc20d605371dae6ed639f40998727b14374044b3f4a89472a96cbb005474d771e84a57bc7dff743ac5017f7755f03bbc5)

Comment: Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`. We cannot copy/paste data from images.

Comment: @neilfws Kindly have a look, I have printed first 76 rows of my df with all columns through subset () function. I hope this suffices.

Comment: @Pranav_b please `dput(dogri_vot)` and copy and paste the console output into your question

Comment: @hello_friend I apologise. I have edited the question by pasting as you (and neilfws) guided. I didn't do it earlier because it was a very long output. Thanks.

Comment: @hello_friend It wont' let me paste as the lines exceed the limit. Should I URL it (if that's not discouraged)?

Comment: @Pranav_b use the following code `dput(head(dogri_vot, 76))`

Comment: It is not clear from your description on which lines require removal. It appears to be a random list of "Germinate" and "Singleton".

Comment: @hello_friend Kindly see the 'edit' in the question. I had to use an external link to upload the output as the characters exceeded the limit

Comment: @Dave2e Sorry for not being clear. There are more entries for ' Geminate' than the 'Singleton'. I wish to remove those from the 'Geminates' that do not occur as 'Singleton'. The words are minimal pair differing at two levels, Singleton and Geminate (as written in col. 'Filename').

Comment: @Pranav_b please upvote and accept my solution if it does what you require

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
# Store a counter vector counting each comsenants value: ctr => integer vector
ctr <- with(df, ave(Consonant, Consonant, FUN = seq.int))

# Number of unique Consonant values: n_vals => integer scalar
n_vals <- length(unique(df$Consonant))

# Drop un-matched records: sbst_df => data.frame
sbst_df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, Filter(function(x){nrow(x) == n_vals}, 
                                            split(dogri_vot, ctr))), row.names = NULL)
```

Data:

```
dogri_vot <- structure(list(V1 = 1:75, Filename = c("AK_baagge.TextGrid", 
"AK_baagi.TextGrid", "AK_bagga.TextGrid", "AK_buute.TextGrid", 
"AK_buutte.TextGrid", "AK_chaakki.TextGrid", "AK_chape.TextGrid", 
"AK_chappe.TextGrid", "AK_fati.TextGrid", "AK_fatti.TextGrid", 
"AK_gada.TextGrid", "AK_gadda.TextGrid", "AK_jaaddi.TextGrid", 
"AK_jaadi.TextGrid", "AK_katha.TextGrid", "AK_kute.TextGrid", 
"AK_kutte.TextGrid", "AK_raajegi.TextGrid", "AK_raajjegi.TextGrid", 
"AK_sada.TextGrid", "AK_saja.TextGrid", "AK_sajja.TextGrid", 
"AK_saka.TextGrid", "AK_sakka.TextGrid", "AK_tapa.TextGrid", 
"AK_tappa.TextGrid", "AK_topa.TextGrid", "AK_toppa.TextGrid", 
"DS_baagge.TextGrid", "DS_baagi.TextGrid", "DS_baga.TextGrid", 
"DS_bagga.TextGrid", "DS_buute.TextGrid", "DS_buutte.TextGrid", 
"DS_chaakki.TextGrid", "DS_chaaku.TextGrid", "DS_chape.TextGrid", 
"DS_chappe.TextGrid", "DS_fatti.TextGrid", "DS_gada.TextGrid", 
"DS_gadda.TextGrid", "DS_jaaddi.TextGrid", "DS_jaadi.TextGrid", 
"DS_katha.TextGrid", "DS_kattha.TextGrid", "DS_kute.TextGrid", 
"DS_kutte.TextGrid", "DS_sada.TextGrid", "DS_sadda.TextGrid", 
"DS_saka.TextGrid", "DS_sakka.TextGrid", "DS_tapa.TextGrid", 
"DS_tappa.TextGrid", "DS_topa.TextGrid", "DS_toppa.TextGrid", 
"MS_baagge.TextGrid", "MS_baagi.TextGrid", "MS_baga.TextGrid", 
"MS_bagga.TextGrid", "MS_buute.TextGrid", "MS_buutte.TextGrid", 
"MS_chaakki.TextGrid", "MS_chaaku.TextGrid", "MS_chape.TextGrid", 
"MS_chappe.TextGrid", "MS_fati.TextGrid", "MS_fatti.TextGrid", 
"MS_gadda.TextGrid", "MS_jaaddi.TextGrid", "MS_jaadi.TextGrid", 
"MS_katha.TextGrid", "MS_kattha.TextGrid", "MS_kute.TextGrid", 
"MS_kutte.TextGrid", "MS_raajegi.TextGrid"), Speaker = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Consonant = c("Geminate", 
"Singleton", "Geminate", "Singleton", "Geminate", "Geminate", 
"Singleton", "Geminate", "Singleton", "Geminate", "Singleton", 
"Geminate", "Geminate", "Singleton", "Singleton", "Singleton", 
"Geminate", "Singleton", "Geminate", "Singleton", "Singleton", 
"Geminate", "Singleton", "Geminate", "Singleton", "Geminate", 
"Singleton", "Geminate", "Geminate", "Singleton", "Singleton", 
"Geminate", "Singleton", "Geminate", "Geminate", "Singleton", 
"Singleton", "Geminate", "Geminate", "Singleton", "Geminate", 
"Geminate", "Singleton", "Singleton", "Geminate", "Singleton", 
"Geminate", "Singleton", "Geminate", "Singleton", "Geminate", 
"Singleton", "Geminate", "Singleton", "Geminate", "Geminate", 
"Singleton", "Singleton", "Geminate", "Singleton", "Geminate", 
"Geminate", "Singleton", "Singleton", "Geminate", "Singleton", 
"Geminate", "Geminate", "Geminate", "Singleton", "Singleton", 
"Geminate", "Singleton", "Geminate", "Singleton"), VOT.dn = c(2.6688227, 
5.3873637, 3.4600502, 1.5246856, 1.2237697, 5.7330285, 1.192124, 
1.732151, 1.7444548, 1.7133051, 1.4753655, 0.9625276, 1.6766487, 
2.7441848, 7.37298, 2.7602911, 4.3993992, 5.9935975, 7.010274, 
2.5616875, 5.5951297, 3.9080006, 2.2465927, 3.2889385, 1.0705113, 
1.2967303, 1.5396249, 0.9897444, 3.2001336, 4.6939881, 2.6724766, 
1.9066545, 2.0054339, 1.8826236, 6.0663448, 5.1022693, 2.3050381, 
0.9959057, 1.4804389, 1.6683009, 2.4245469, 3.164039, 2.0648408, 
6.2447475, 6.65083, 2.4059111, 1.7843229, 1.0648602, 1.0570399, 
2.3740635, 1.9817196, 2.0791699, 1.1780412, 1.5373779, 1.250764, 
1.5723396, 1.1632927, 0.992896, 1.7316937, 0.9249825, 1.031242, 
4.9168736, 2.7092267, 1.0511894, 1.0526788, 1.0565391, 1.0764399, 
0.8969808, 1.490155, 1.2981336, 5.8849308, 5.5543907, 2.3143402, 
2.906642, 3.190377), VOT = c(0.026688227, 0.053873637, 0.034600502, 
0.015246856, 0.012237697, 0.057330285, 0.01192124, 0.01732151, 
0.017444548, 0.017133051, 0.014753655, 0.009625276, 0.016766487, 
0.027441848, 0.0737298, 0.027602911, 0.043993992, 0.059935975, 
0.07010274, 0.025616875, 0.055951297, 0.039080006, 0.022465927, 
0.032889385, 0.010705113, 0.012967303, 0.015396249, 0.009897444, 
0.032001336, 0.046939881, 0.026724766, 0.019066545, 0.020054339, 
0.018826236, 0.060663448, 0.051022693, 0.023050381, 0.009959057, 
0.014804389, 0.016683009, 0.024245469, 0.03164039, 0.020648408, 
0.062447475, 0.0665083, 0.024059111, 0.017843229, 0.010648602, 
0.010570399, 0.023740635, 0.019817196, 0.020791699, 0.011780412, 
0.015373779, 0.01250764, 0.015723396, 0.011632927, 0.00992896, 
0.017316937, 0.009249825, 0.01031242, 0.049168736, 0.027092267, 
0.010511894, 0.010526788, 0.010565391, 0.010764399, 0.008969808, 
0.01490155, 0.012981336, 0.058849308, 0.055543907, 0.023143402, 
0.02906642, 0.03190377), xsampa = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), Place = c("Velar", "Velar", "Velar", 
"Retroflex", "Retroflex", "Velar", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Retroflex", 
"Retroflex", "Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", 
"Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", 
"Palatal", "Palatal", "Dental/alveolar", "Palatal", "Palatal", 
"Velar", "Velar", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", 
"Velar", "Velar", "Velar", "Velar", "Palatal", "Palatal", "Velar", 
"Velar", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Retroflex", "Dental/alveolar", 
"Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", 
"Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", 
"Dental/alveolar", "Velar", "Velar", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", 
"Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", 
"Retroflex", "Retroflex", "Velar", "Velar", "Bilabial", "Bilabial", 
"Retroflex", "Retroflex", "Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", 
"Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", "Dental/alveolar", 
"Dental/alveolar", "Palatal"), Manner = c("Stop", "Stop", "Stop", 
"Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", 
"Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Palatal", "Palatal", 
"Stop", "Palatal", "Palatal", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", 
"Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", 
"Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", 
"Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", 
"Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", 
"Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", 
"Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", "Stop", 
"Palatal"), Voicing = c("Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiceless", 
"Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", 
"Voiceless", "Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiceless", 
"Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiced", 
"Voiced", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", 
"Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiced", 
"Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", 
"Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiced", 
"Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiced", 
"Voiced", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", 
"Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiced", 
"Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", 
"Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiced", "Voiced", "Voiced", 
"Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiceless", "Voiced")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -75L))
```